# Python Function Appears to Return an Empty Series

Tags: python, pandas, function

Im trying to run the following function but for some reason it's not working ...

```
def totals(name_df):
    name_df = df.loc[df['candidate_name'] == 'name_df']
    for i in name_df:
        name_sector = name_df.groupby(['sector_name']) 
        \ ['sector_total'].mean()
        name_industry = name_df.groupby(['industry_name']) 
        \ ['industry_total'].mean()
        name_contributor= name_df.groupby(['contributor_name']) 
        \ ['contributor_total'].mean()
        names = [name_sector, name_industry, name_contributor]

    return names

print(totals('Random Person Name'))
```

I get the following Traceback message:

```
[Series([], Name: sector_total, dtype: float64), Series([], Name: 
industry_total, dtype: float64), Series([], Name: contributor_total, 
dtype: float64)]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That is not a traceback message

Comment: Don't put quotes around `name_df` in your conditional index of `df`, instead do `df.loc[df['candidate_name'] == name_df]`.  Otherwise the string value you pass in via the `name_df` argument goes unused.  As it is, you're telling it to match the string `'name_df'` instead of `'Random Person Name'`.  Voting to close for typographical error.

Comment: Also note that `names` is not guaranteed to exist by the time you want to return it.  It's also a little odd to have the string you're passing in, which matches to `candidate_name`, called `name_df`, when it's not a data frame and when you actually *do* want to define a data frame called `name_df` within your function.  Those are not the reasons you have the problem you've identified, but they are still issues with your code worth considering.